# How do I set my application's dock name?

Tags: apache-flex, macos, mxml, dock

I'm making a Flex app and I'd like to know how to set the name of my app as it appears when the user hovers over it in the dock. Here's a screenshot of it now:

[image: LimudYomi Dock Screenshot]

I'd like a space between the lowercase 'd' and the uppercase `Y`. What part of my app's XML file must I edit to change that text in the gray tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer applies to both Flex Builder 3 applications and Flash Builder 4 applications. Every newly created project gets a project-name.mxml (main application file) and a project-name-app.xml (application descriptor) file.

The application descriptor file is an XML file, pre-formatted with XML nodes that tell the Flex SDK different things about your app such as the initial width and height, the copyright notice and more. There's an XML node called <filename> that sets the name of the application file (.app on Mac, .exe on Windows). The value for <filename> will also dictate the name of the app in the Mac Dock and in the Windows taskbar. There's a <name> node that is responsible for indicating the name of the application. The value here will typically display in the app if you use native system chrome. Outside of this scenario the <name> property isn't that useful.

NOTE: While you can change the value of <filename> in order to change the name of the app in the Mac Dock and Windows taskbar, be careful not to use special characters like the registered trademark and copyright symbol. The actual filename of the application should not have these special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is in Foo-app.xml, where "Foo" is the name of your project.  This file is generated when you create your AIR app project.  There is a tag called "filename" that you can set to whatever you like and it will get shown as the app name when you mouse over the icon in the dock.  So do something like this:

```
<filename>Limud Yomi</filename>
```

A description of the "filename" tag, from the Adobe documentation: "The name used for the application executable, install directory, and other references to the application in the operating system."

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Edited my answer to one that actually works. :)